# What do I put here?

Tags: passports, canada, fees-and-charges

[image]

I'm applying for a passport and I'm unsure of what to put for this section. It's 160 for a 10 year passport, plus it says there's a 25$ fee. So do I just put 185?

Comment: You say "it" says there's a $25 fee, but what is "it"? Are you requesting express or urgent processing? Here is the fee info I found: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/fees/passport-canada.html

Comment: It says on the passport that it includes a  "25$ consular services fee". What ddoes that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're referring to is the fee mentioned here in PPTC 153:

[image]

As it says on the form, the $25 fee **is included** in the $160 application fee. It is not an additional fee. Further down, you can see that if you cancel your application or are refused, then only the $25 portion of the whole $160 is refundable.

So, you want to pay $160.

Comment: For non-native English speakers, the word *included* in this context describes _membership_, not _addition_. Membership: "Chocolate chips are included in this cookie" (Cookies contain chocolate). Addition: "I included a cheque with this envelope" (Envelopes do not normally contain cheques, so I added one). Thus, "the fee is included" means "the fee is contained", not "the fee is added".